# Order of the maximum torus containing Frobenius endomorphism for Elkies' primes

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let E be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Suppose that $t^2-4p\not\equiv 0\pmod{l}$, where $l$ is an Elkies prime and $t$ the norm of Frobenius endomorphism $\varphi$.  Then $\varphi$ acts on $E[l]$ as a matrix $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} \alpha &0\\ 0&\beta \end{smallmatrix} \right)$

and let $T\subset PGL_2(F_l)$be a maximal torus containing $\varphi$. In other words $T=\{\left( \begin{smallmatrix} \alpha &0\\ 0&\beta \end{smallmatrix} \right) | \alpha, \beta \in F_l^{*}\}$. 
Then the image $\bar{T}$ of $T$ in $PGL_2(F_l)$ is cyclic of order $l-1$ and isomorphic to $F_l^{*}$

When $T$ is non-split, it is isomorphic to $F_{l^2}^{*}$ and the order of $\bar{T}$ is $l+1$.

I can't see how $\bar{T}$ is cyclic of order $l+1$.

Schoof, (1995) [Counting points on eliptic curve over finite field](http://www.numdam.org/article/JTNB_1995__7_1_219_0.pdf)  page no:240.proposition 6.3

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: See [Silverman's book](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf). $\phi^2 - t \phi + p= 0$ means $\mathbb{Z}[\phi] \simeq \mathbb{Z}[\frac{t+\sqrt{t^2-4p}}{2}] $ is a subring of $End(E)$ as well as the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{t^2-4p})$. The fact $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ has a non-negative norm (the degree $deg(\psi)$) means it is imaginary quadratic ie. $t^2-4p < 0$.

When looking at $\phi, [n]$ acting on $E[l]$ we obtain $[l] P = O$, ie. $[l] = [0]$ so we are working modulo $l$.

Comment: If $l$ is prime and $E[l]$ is more than $\{O\}$ then $\mathbb{F}_l[\phi] \simeq \mathbb{F}_l[x]/(x^2-t_l x+p_l)$. This polynomial is irreducible iff $t_l^2-4p_l \equiv t^2-4p \not \equiv 0 \bmod l$, in that case $\mathbb{F}_l[x]/(x^2-t_l x+p_l)$ is a field with $l^2$ elements.

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you for the answer, but I am not clear, In the splitting case I can see it is of order $l-1$ as , I have two copies of $\mathbb{F}^{*}$ and modulo the center (diagonal elements of order $l-1$), then order is $l-1$. But in the non splitting case, why $l+1$, can you please explain, what is the center and order